# Nested countif's frying my brain

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

What I want is the following scenario:

- If all values are "Pass" then display "Passed"
- If all values are "Fail" then display "Failed"
- If all values are "Incomplete" then display "Not Started"
- If all values are blank/empty then display "No Use Cases"
- If any combination then display "In Progress"

I'm like 85% there but I lost my inception top so I forget where I am.

So far I have the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G:G,"Pass"),"PASSED",IF(COUNTIF(G:G,"Fail"),"FAILED",IF(COUNTIF(G:G,"Incomplete"),"IN PROGRESS","NO USE CASES")))
```

Please send help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following line will solve your problem as I understand it.

```
=IF(COUNTA(G:H)=0,"NO USE CASES",IF(COUNTIF(G:H,"Pass")=COUNTA(G:H),"PASSED",IF(COUNTIF(G:H,"Fail")=COUNTA(G:H),"FAILED",IF(COUNTIF(G:H,"Incomplete")=COUNTA(G:H),"NOT STARTED","IN PROGRESS"))))
```

The process I took was to create a simple test excel sheet and just use a couple of variables in rows g and h. The key thing I found was that countif maybe a bit misnamed, it returns the number of matches. In the original formula it would return true if there was at least one 'Pass' and then stop any further processing. Using the **counta** function, it checks to see if **all** entries are Pass, if that is true it return PASSED.

Interestingly, this would also return true if there were **no** Pass entries. So, the first thing the formula does is use counta to check how many non-blank cells there are. If there are 0 then it returns 'No Use Cases', otherwise it goes through processing the rules.

Comment: I think this does everything!  Note that due to a header I had to change the first 0 to a 1 and then add `-1` to all the `counta` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G:H,"Pass")=COUNTA(G:H),"PASSED",IF(COUNTIF(G:H,"Fail")=COUNTA(G:H),"FAILED",IF(COUNTIF(G:H,"Incomplete")=COUNTA(G:H),"IN PROGRESS","NO USE CASES")))
```

Explanation:

`IF` requires logical test but instead you used only `COUNTIF(G:H,"something")` which returns the number of instances of the word. The suggested formula compares that number to the total number of cells containing any data.

Comment: I tested a couple scenarios and with both it stills says `no use cases`

Comment: I should probably mention that G:H is a formula not an explicit value.  Not sure if that is causing the issue

Comment: I also just discovered another issue.  I'm actually only worried about column G.  Not sure why the original formula had G:H but I have changed it.  Sorry.

Comment: I tried yours with G:G and still get `NO USE CASES`

Comment: If you have header row or other values, which should not be considered by the formula, you should account for them. If its 1 cell / row you should subtract 1 from COUNTA(G). If 2 header rows -> substract 2, etc.

Comment: Just figured that out, I do have a header.  Had to do `COUNTA(G:G)-1` and now it's better.  I think I still need a tweak though

Comment: So I think there's a problem.  If there are no use cases, all the expressions evaluate true `COUNTIF(G:G,"FAIL") = 0`, `COUNTA(G:G) = 0`.  Ideas?

Comment: I think since I'll never be handing out this spreadsheet with no use cases I'll just ignore this little glitch.  Here is the current formula which seems to work in every other case: `=IF(COUNTIF(G:G,"Pass")=COUNTA(G:G)-1,"PASSED",IF(COUNTIF(G:G,"Fail")=COUNTA(G:G)-1,"FAILED",IF(COUNTIF(G:G,"Incomplete")=COUNTA(G:G)-1,"NOT STARTED",IF(COUNTIF(G:G,"")=COUNTA(G:G)-1,"NO USE CASES","IN PROGRESS"))))`